# WPF purpose of `(arg) => true)`

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

While reading [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159939/Command-Binding-inside-DataTemplate-in-Parent-Chil) on Command Binding in DataTemplate, I saw this:

```
public DelegateCommand<string> AddBrand
{
    get
    {
        return this.addBrand ?? (this.addBrand = new DelegateCommand<string>( this.ExecuteAddBrand, (arg) => true));
    }
}
```

which is a function inside `BrandsViewModel.cs` to add a Brand. I have questions about the line below:

```
this.addBrand = new DelegateCommand<string>( this.ExecuteAddBrand, (arg) => true));
```

My understanding is that `AddBrand` is a command registered to the `Add Brand` button in the `View`, and this adds a delegate method to be called upon the click of the button. Specifically, `this.ExecuteAddBrand` is the method to be executed. However, what is the purpose of `(arg) => true)`? What does it even mean? Thanks!

Comment: It's just a fancy syntax and name of an anonymous method. `a => b` is the same as `delegate(_type_ a){return b;}`. The advantage is that the type of `a` is inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a lambda that represents a method (or expression) that accepts one argument and always returns true regardless of the input. "Given `string arg`, return `true`".

Perhaps a clearer example is on a list:

```
var names = List<string>(...); // populate, etc
var containsA = names.FindAll(x => x.Contains("A"));
```

In the above, I'm using a lambda to express a "predicate" - essentially a filter condition; for any name, it returns true if the name contains an A. `FindAll` returns all the items that match the predicate. We could also do:

```
var everybody = names.FindAll(x => true);
var nobody = names.FindAll(x => false);
```

(although that is obviously a bit silly)

More specific to `DelegateCommand`: basically, the second parameter is `canExecuteMethod`, and it is basically saying "yes, it can always execute, regardless of the value". In the more general case, this can act as a filter on when it is/isn't appropriate to use the method. The `canExecuteMethod` parameter can also be omitted or passed as `null`, if that would be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The operator `=>` is used when we want to write a lambda expression.

You can think it of as a normal method, where the things left to `=>` are the parameters (the input) of the method and the thing right the `=>` is that the method returns (output).

For instance

```
x=>x*x
```

If we input 3, we will get as output 9.

Lambda expressions are really usefull in `LINQ`.

For instance, say that we have a collection called `customers` of objects of type `Customer`, whose defintion is the following one:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Let then that we want to get the customers that have age greater than 18. Then we could do this like below:

```
var adults = from customer in customers
             where customer.Age>18
             select customer;
```

However, we could get also the same result, as below:

```
var adults = customers.Where(x => x.Age>18);
```

In the latter case, we pass in the `Where` method a lambda expression.

> what is the purpose of (arg) => true)? What does it even mean?

Now in your case the above lambda accepts an argument called `arg` and always returns `true`.